# filter file name based on different extension patterns

Tags: python

I have a python application in which I have defined some tools with extensions.

```
extList = ["*pdf","*.cod","*log*","*.log.*"]
```

Now how to return files based on these extensions.

I used endWith() string method to match extension but it will not follow patterns.

```
extList = ["*pdf","*.cod","*log*","*.log.*"]

if os.path.isfile(unicode(path)):
    if unicode(path).endswith(tuple(extList)):
         print("match")
```

how to write regEx to match following patterns in single RegEx ?
please suggest RegEx.

How to Write RegEx to Match File extension patterns like below:-

```
*.pdf
*.pdf*
*.pdf.*
*.pdf*.*
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) module instead of `glob`:
Example:

```
import glob

extList = ["*pdf","*.cod","*log*","*.log.*"]
any(fnmatch.fnmatch(path, ext) for ext in extList)
```

Test:

```
>>> any(fnmatch.fnmatch(u'test.pdf', ext) for ext in extList)
True
>>> any(fnmatch.fnmatch(u'test.zip', ext) for ext in extList)
False
```

Comment: Still, my path is unicode string  (QString) so i can't use fmatch directly.